Flutter, I added Flutter Intl, instance != null "No instance of S present in the widget
Flutter, I added Flutter Intl, did everything according to the instructions, but when starting there is always a red screen and an Assertion failed error:
file:/MyApp/lib/generated/l10n.dart:44:12
instance != null
"No instance of S present in the widget tree. Did you add S.delegate in localizationsDelegates?"
The relevant error-causing widget was:
NavBar navbar.dart file to which I want to transfer
I have already tried other localization methods and always have the same problem, which gives a Null value
I double-checked everything, the imports are correct everywhere, there are no errors in the code
Flutter Intl Initilialize
Create folder lib\generated\intl\messages_all.dart and intl\messages_en.dart and lib\generated\l10n.dart
lib\l10n\intl_en.arb
{
"name_ivana": "Ivan Ivanova"
}
``
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizati`your text`ons/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:myAppr/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:myApp/generated/l10n.dart';
import 'package:myApp/main_app.dart';
import 'package:myAppw/views/navigation/navbar.dart';
import 'package:myApp/views/pin_code/create_pin_code_screen.dart';
import 'package:myApp/views/pin_co`your text`de/pin_code_widget.dart';

void main() async {
  await _initHive();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await _initSecureStorage();
  //await S.load(const Locale('en')); 
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

Future<void> _initHive() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox("login");
}

Future<void> _initSecureStorage() async {
  FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
  // Проверяем наличие сохраненного пин-кода
  String? savedPin = await storage.read(key: 'pin_code');
  runApp(MyApp(savedPin: savedPin));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? savedPin;

  const MyApp({super.key, this.savedPin});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
         // Ваш делегат локализации
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        S.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
      
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //home: widget.savedPin != null ? PinCodeWidget(savedPin: widget.savedPin!) : const CreatePinCodeScreen(),
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: widget.savedPin != null 
                 ? PinCodeWidget(savedPin: widget.savedPin!)
                  : const CreatePinCodeScreen(),
                  drawer: const NavBar(),
          );
          
          
        },
      ),
      
    );
  }
}

``


Add this Line in  Build method : ->  S.load(
Locale.fromSubtags(
languageCode: Locale('en').languageCode , // shared!.getString('lang') ?? 'en',
),
);
